# Generics compile error in C# (but works in VB.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, generics, compiler-errors

I'm having an odd problem with generics.  I receive the following compile errors:

> The best overloaded method match has some invalid arguments
>
> Argument '1': cannot convert from 'EntityBase' to 'T'

The error is in `EntityWrapper.DoSomethingElse`, see below:

```
public abstract class EntityBase
{
    public static bool DoSomething<T>(T entity, string someArg) where T : EntityBase
    {
        // implementation doesn't matter
        return true;
    }
}

public class EntityWrapper<T> where T : EntityBase
{
    private EntityBase _entity;

    public void DoSomethingElse()
    {

        EntityBase.DoSomething<T>(_entity, "some arg"); // <--- error here ---
    }

}
```

I have a VB.NET version of this code that compiles and executes just fine, so I would expect it to work in C#.

What am I missing here?

Finally, though it shouldn't matter, but this is VS2008, .NET 3.5.

Comment: Is Option Strict enabled for your working VB.NET version?

Comment: I assume it was, that is the default I used for those others projects.  But now I start to wonder...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me show you why your code is invalid: Imagine I create an `EntityWrapper<MyEntity>`, where `MyEntity` derives from `BaseEntity`:

```
var myWrapper = new EntityWrapper<MyEntity>();
```

What happens inside EntityWrapper? This:

```
EntityBase.DoSomething<T>(_entity, "some arg");
```

becomes

```
EntityBase.DoSomething<MyEntity>(_entity, "some arg");
```

which is invalid: DoSomething expects a `MyEntity` as its first argument, but you pass a `BaseEntity`. This is what the error `Argument '1': cannot convert from 'EntityBase' to 'T'` means.

---

How to fix this? In EntityWrapper, declare `_entity` as follows:

```
private T _entity;
```

This allows you to keep `_entity` *statically* typed to the concrete subtype of `BaseEntity`.

Comment: Yep, it was `private T _entity;` that I needed.  While @JoelCoehoorn answer was also right, it was here that I converted the old code incorrectly.  Thanks for the elephant-s[potting.

Answer (score 3):

Just omit the `<T>`. Type inference will figure it out:

```
EntityBase.DoSomething(_entity, "some arg");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could call the method as follows:

```
EntityBase.DoSomething<EntityBase>(_entity, "some arg");
```

The compiler fails to cast `_entity` (which is `EntityBase`) to `T` (which is specified in the method call).